# Converting consecutive and repeated questions in an excel column into a table

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with repeated questions down a single column. It spans over 3000 rows deep. The data is confidential so I can only provide the example image below:

[image]

I wish to take this data and group the answers into a table so it is suitable for export into an XML file. Example Result:

[image]

I have some educational experience with c# and stream read/write but I'm sure there would be a VBA macro that could perform this much quicker. I have discovered the data is inconsistent due to unanswered questions not having a blank cell beneath. This was due to me attempting to convert the data from headings and text in word.

This is my first post; some pointers on how to write a better question would be appreciated if necessary.

Comment: on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried using a pivot table? Although your input data isn't really setup for pivot input.

Comment: This site is full of code examples that could serve as good jumping off points for you. Give it a shot and ask about what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @OldUgly I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a rather manual solution, instead of using VBA Macro. You'd essentially need to carry out the following steps, then if you're confident with the outcome (and the logic of identifying outliers) record a macro for ease of use later.

1. Use column B to "Mark" each "Start", probably by finding the string "Reference Code". For B1 that would be: `=IF(TRIM(A1)="Reference Code","#","")` Fill this to the end of column B, and add a `"#"` into the next row of column B for good measure
2. For column C, you'll string the values if B is blank, or reset if B has "#". C2 would be: `=IF(B2="#",A2,C1&"§"&A2)`Fill this to the end of column C. Now column C keeps concatenating values until it reaches a new "Reference Code" identified by `"#"`
3. For column D, you'll need to "mark" the last line of every set; this is the only line with valid data, all the others before are incomplete. D1 would be `=IF(B2="#","*","")`Fill this is to the end of column D
4. Copy column C & D and Paste Values. This locks in the concatenated strings, and the end markers.
5. Sort by Column D, and delete any rows without the end marker "*". Then delete column D altogether
6. Using "Data">"Text to Columns", split Column C up. You will use the "Delimited" setting, select "Other" and use "§" as the delimiter (it was used in Step 2).

Till here it is all automated, and you might like to record a macro with all the previous steps to run it again if you need to.

7. Now the columns C to L contain the relevant data, alternating between the keys "Reference Code", "Question 1", etc. and the relevant value data in between. Now sorting by each field name column (C, E, G, I, K) you should expect to always find the keyword; working from left to right, any column that does not have the correct key consistently has incorrect data. Shift the data in such columns/rows to the right until they fit into place. This effectively takes out the missing values.
8. Delete the field name columns, and you've got yourself a full set of data with empty values reflected.